# Save multiple Django formsets into a single database field

Tags: python, django, database, tuples, formset

**Acutal situation**
I have a db table called "invoice" where all Django formsets are being saved successfully. So, table looks like this:

```
item_id|quantity|description|price|taxes|total|customer_id|invoice_id|
 56        1        apple     100    0    100     567        1766     
 12        1        banana     40    0     40     567        1766
```

**The problem**
If, for example, invoice has 100 items, I will have 100 rows inside invoice db table.

**Question**
I think there's a better and more efficient way to do the same without making the db heavier.
So, I would like to save these items coming from the formsets **into a single field** as a list of tuples of invoice items? For example the new table will look like this:

```
|                   items                    |customer_id|invoice_id|
["fruit", [apple,banana], "price", [100,40]]      567       1766
```

Comment: The way to do this is by making extra tables, this is a form of *database normalization* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new model which takes inheritance from your Invoice model:

I just writing you a logic. You need to update this.

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField() # Item description (ex. banana)
    customer_id = models.(Your customer_id) 
    invoice_id = models.(Your invoice_id ) 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.description,self.customer_id,self.invoice_id
    
class InvoiceLite(models.Model):
    items  = models.OneToOneField(Invoice,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So you can now see the database for the InvoiceLite model.

I hope this gave you the light to do what you asking for.